# Giving the UID for the document's name

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know what is the best practice to save users preferences in my firestore database.
I would try to explain with an example...

### Case 1

I have this kind of Document in my "users" Collection (the name is random generated by Firebase) with 3 fields :

- **user_uid** : String
- **nickname** : String
- **android_lover** : boolean

In my Android project, when I want to search the Document of the user "DFDDE45554SDC", I search where user_uid = "DFDDE45554SDC".

### Case 2

I have this kind of Document in my "users" Collection (the name is created with the UID of the user) with 2 fields :

- **nickname** : String
- **android_lover** : boolean

In my Android project, when I want to search the Document of the user "DFDDE45554SDC", I just search the Document "DFDDE45554SDC".

---

I specify : I don't want duplicate users.
So, what is the best practice (security, optimisation,...) ? Why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest that `Case 2` is more effective, for a few reasons:

- We already know the user's ID, so don't need to use a different ID here.
- Using `usersCollection.document(userId)` is simple to construct and is a direct `DocumentReference`, rather than a `Query`, therefore:

  - A `DocumentReference` can be stored in the Firestore database, whereas a `Query` cannot.
  - A `DocumentReference` would likely scale better than instructing the Firestore database to perform a filter query using `whereEqualTo("user_uid", userId)` (although with indexing, the performance difference is likely negligible at this point).
  - A `Query` will always return a collection of results (even if there is only 1), rather than the exact document.
- There isn't currently a need for a different randomly-generated ID for each document within the users collection because the user ID is already unique.
- You only need 1 document for each user, so this is a sure-fire way to ensure there won't be any duplicates.

The only real incentive I can think of to use `Case 1` would be to standardise your document naming scheme with other collections in your database, but this doesn't really matter so much with Firestore.

For a quick example of the two in Android:

**Case 1**

```
db.collection("users")
    .whereEqualTo("user_uid", "DFDDE45554SDC")
    .limit(1)
    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    // Even with limit(1), we still receive a collection
                    // so iterate this to obtain the desired document
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**Case 2**

```
db.collection("users")
    .document("DFDDE45554SDC")
    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                // We have access to the single desired document directly
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think it depends. Suppose there are two login options provided to users facebook, phone Auth. So in this case one user will have two uid for one unique user document in firestore. Therefore in this case Case 1 should be preferred.