# Is better to use random ID for firebase document or manual ID?

Tags: android, firebase

In your opinion, is better to use the random ID auto generated by firebase for a new document or it's not a bad practice if I choose the name of the document so that I can perform easier query?
For example, instead of searching inside the collection "users" in all the random id document, and then search for a user with the field "email =  test@gmail.com", should I assign to my document the title "test@gmail.com" and then search on the collection "users" for the document with the name "test@gmail.com"?
What do you think?

Comment: When someone downvote a question, can He explain the reason please?!

Comment: I donot know which one give you but that person is write because you are not explaining you main problem in your question.This portal is not for about our thoughts. If you want solution so please ask a valuable question.

Comment: I asked an advice to know what's the best practice for a programmer when I need to create a new document in firestore..it's a bad question?

Comment: yes bro because you can do what you want so in programming so what's the problem is here you have to ask about your problem. While in opinion about your question you have to use random instead of custom.

Comment: I now found this question, which was appreciated and is the same as mine   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915485/giving-the-uid-for-the-documents-name?rq=1

Comment: Basically you have you ranswer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult to answer because you're asking for an opinion about your database structure when we have no concept of your use case.

However, let me throw out a couple of thoughts.

> if I choose the name of the document so that I can perform easier
>   query

The key name is not related nor has anything to do with the child data it contains as far as a query goes. take a look

```
users
   -Y89j9kksd0kskd //a users uid for example
       email: "thing@test.com"
   -y9099k,msp,sps
       email: "dude@thing.com"
```

If you want to query for an email of "dude@thing.com", the query 'ignores' each child key (-Y89... -y90... etc) and looks at the email: node within.

If you name the keys and do a query, it still makes no difference, it still ignores that key. It is returned as the key property of the snapshot but that's not the issue here since we know the value is the email of the email: child.

```
users
   -thing@test.com
       email: "thing@test.com"
   -dude@thing.com
       email: "dude@thing.com"
```

The issue here is that . cannot be used in key names so now you have to encode/decode every key. That's a lot of extra code.

More importantly, if the email address changes, you will have to change *every occurrence of that email address in ALL of your data*. And since you can't change keys, you would have to delete every node and re-write it. Ugh.

Using the first example is the way to go. You can keep a reference to that user throughout the app (using the uid for example) and no matter what child data changes within that node (email for example), the rest of the data remains unaffected.

There is a but here... there's always a but.

Sometimes you may want to know if a piece of data exists at specific path - in those cases, you can access it directly. For example

```
users
   -Y89j9kksd0kskd //a users uid for example
       email: "thing@test.com"
       things_i_like
          food:
            pizza: true
            taco: true
          color:
            blue: true
          wine:
            ornellaia: true
```

Suppose I have this users uid of -Y89j9kksd0kskd and I want to see if pizza is a food they like. Instead of querying the food node I can access it directly at

```
/uid/things_i_like/food/pizza
```

and see if the value is true (or see if it exists)

or to see if they like the wonderful Italian Ornellaia wine, test for true (or existance) at

```
/uid/things_i_like/wine/ornellaia
```

As you can see, leveraging the uid or Firebase created keys at a top level doesn't affect your queries but when you know you want to access a specific datapoint within a known node, naming the node keys is one solution.

It's all a balance and depends on what kind of queries you want to run... If you wanted to know all users that like pizza, that would be a query (and a slightly different structure) so you wouldn't know the specific path and a query would be needed.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! What if I need to query a subcollection document, without know the root document name? So, for example ---> users(Collection) --> abc1234qwerty (document with random ID wich contains the fields "email = test@gmail.com") ---> payment(Collection) ---> efgh5678poiuyt(document with random ID). If i want to get "efgh5678poiuyt" document without know that is under "abc1234qwerty", what should I do? Two different query, where first I get the "abc1234qwerty" id and then I search inside the "payment" collection, or can I use a single query?

Comment: @RipError Hmm. That structure doesn't really match a query and we would need to know what data you want. In other words, it doesn't sound like you need to query at all. If you know the user you want, you would also know their user id. So the path would be `/users/uid/payment/efgh5678poiuyt` and then read the value of that node. Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, so it may be a good idea to ask a separate question with some more details.

Comment: Yeah, now I understand how to do that. I was wondering if you could do 2 queries simultaneously without  saving locally the random uid.